# No Webcam detected or webcam is not working?

Tags: windows, windows-10, webcam, dell-inspiron

I was using windows7 but now I have installed windows10 but in windows10 camera is not working.

I am using Dell Inspiron Laptop.

When I open cyberlink webcam then it shows me this message.

[image: CyberLink YouCam]

In device manager it is showing imaging device but in subfolder showing unknown device.

Actually by mistake I have uninstalled it eariler but I installed it again.

Before uninstalling it, it was showing a differnt thing in subfolder and working fine but now it is showing unknown device.

See this pic:-

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Did you check on Device Manager if your WebCam is detected at all? Maybe it is just missing a driver?

Comment: @Darius Please check the question again, I have edited it.

Comment: Does Dell provide Windows 10 specific drivers for your laptop?

Comment: @Ramhound No, They're not providing anything. Laptop is working fine but webcam is not working fine.

Comment: What is the exact model of your Dell Inspiron? What is the ID of the Unknown USB Device? Right click on unknown device->Properties->Details->Device's ID

Comment: Dell Inspiron N4010, Property is "Device Description" @alljamin .

Comment: Click on "details" in "properties" and find "hardware id": [like here](https://philipyip.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/611.png). Copy and paste it to your question.